# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(java.lang.String)' - Java CentOS 7

Tags: java, linux, centos7, speech-to-text, azure-speech

My application is a spring boot java project connecting to the azure services for converting speech to text, analyzing sentiment and translating. I am trying to deploy my application to a centos 7 VM, but I get the error in the title when calling my endpoint converting speech to text. I have no problem running the application from my local windows 10 machine. Here are my logs:

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

2022-04-08 13:35:27.482  INFO 30261 --- [           main] .e.t.f.m.ExtractTextFromMediaApplication : Starting ExtractTextFromMediaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.14.1 on speech2text..net with PID 30261 (/usr/local/speech2text/extractTextFromMedia-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /export/home/fos)
2022-04-08 13:35:27.497  INFO 30261 --- [           main] .e.t.f.m.ExtractTextFromMediaApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-04-08 13:35:29.701  INFO 30261 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http)
2022-04-08 13:35:29.724  INFO 30261 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-04-08 13:35:29.725  INFO 30261 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2022-04-08 13:35:29.792  INFO 30261 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-08 13:35:29.792  INFO 30261 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2186 ms
2022-04-08 13:35:30.925  INFO 30261 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-04-08 13:35:31.336  INFO 30261 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-04-08 13:35:31.363  INFO 30261 --- [           main] .e.t.f.m.ExtractTextFromMediaApplication : Started ExtractTextFromMediaApplication in 4.656 seconds (JVM running for 5.295)
2022-04-08 13:35:36.283  INFO 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-08 13:35:36.284  INFO 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-08 13:35:36.285  INFO 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-04-08 13:35:36.821  INFO 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.r.c.e.t.f.m.s.TextFromMediaService     : 20220408133536_videoplayback.mp4 video file was coppied on disk.
2022-04-08 13:35:36.995  INFO 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.r.c.e.t.f.m.s.TextFromMediaService     : Audio file created in path: /tmp/temp_audio/20220408133536_videoplayback_20220408133536.wav
2022-04-08 13:35:37.077 ERROR 30261 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(java.lang.String)'] with root cause
 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(java.lang.String)'
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.setTempDirectory(Native Method) ~[client-sdk-1.19.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.<clinit>(SpeechConfig.java:77) ~[client-sdk-1.19.0.jar!/:na]
        at com...extract.text.from.media.service.ExtractTextFromAudioService.getSpeechConfig(ExtractTextFromAudioService.java:102) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com...extract.text.from.media.service.ExtractTextFromAudioService.continuousRecognitionWithFileWithPhraseListAsync(ExtractTextFromAudioService.java:32) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com...extract.text.from.media.service.TextFromMediaService.getTextFromMediaFile(TextFromMediaService.java:89) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com...extract.text.from.media.service.TextFromMediaService.getTextFromMedia(TextFromMediaService.java:72) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com...extract.text.from.media.controller.MediaToTextMultipartController.extractTextFromMedia(MediaToTextMultipartController.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

This is my pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
   xsi:schemaLocation=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com..</groupId>
   <artifactId>extractTextFromMedia</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>extractTextFromMedia</name>
   <description>Project for extracting the text from media files</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- video to audio -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ws.schild</groupId>
         <artifactId>jave-all-deps</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- azure -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech</groupId>
         <artifactId>client-sdk</artifactId>
         <version>1.20.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- sentiment analysis -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-ai-textanalytics -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
         <artifactId>azure-ai-textanalytics</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.7</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
         <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      </dependency>


   </dependencies>

   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>maven-cognitiveservices-speech</id>
         <name>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech Maven Repository</name>
         <url>https://csspeechstorage.blob.core.windows.net/maven/</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <requiresUnpack>
                  <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech</groupId>
                     <artifactId>client-sdk</artifactId>
                     <version>1.20.0</version>
                  </dependency>
               </requiresUnpack>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

I run my program by building it into a fat .jar file with mvn clean package, transfer the jar to my VM and run it through a service there (with java -jar).

I have installed the packages indicated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-configure-rhel-centos-7
Althrough, I don't entirely understand how my environmental variable should look like there.

I have also tried transferring the whole project folder in the VM and running it there, but I get the same error. I am unsure what to try next.

I've opened a similar issue on github - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1461

L.E: I've managed to run the sample java program in the above github with no problems, so it seems like I have all the required dependencies on the machine. My spring project just doesn't use them for whatever reason.

LE2: find /usr/local/lib64 result:

```
/usr/local/lib64/

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++fs.a

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.la

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24-gdb.py

/usr/local/lib64/liblsan.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/liblsan.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/liblsan.so

/usr/local/lib64/liblsan.la

/usr/local/lib64/liblsan.a

/usr/local/lib64/libasan_preinit.o

/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.4.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.4

/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so

/usr/local/lib64/libasan.la

/usr/local/lib64/libasan.a

/usr/local/lib64/libubsan.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libubsan.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/libubsan.so

/usr/local/lib64/libubsan.la

/usr/local/lib64/libubsan.a

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan_preinit.o

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan.so

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan.la

/usr/local/lib64/libtsan.a

/usr/local/lib64/libsanitizer.spec

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.so.2.0.1

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.so.2

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.so

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.la

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.a

/usr/local/lib64/libmpxwrappers.so.2.0.1

/usr/local/lib64/libmpxwrappers.so.2

/usr/local/lib64/libmpxwrappers.so

/usr/local/lib64/libmpxwrappers.la

/usr/local/lib64/libmpxwrappers.a

/usr/local/lib64/libmpx.spec

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.spec

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.so.5.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.so.5

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.so

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.la

/usr/local/lib64/libcilkrts.a

/usr/local/lib64/libssp.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libssp.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/libssp.so

/usr/local/lib64/libssp.la

/usr/local/lib64/libssp_nonshared.la

/usr/local/lib64/libssp.a

/usr/local/lib64/libssp_nonshared.a

/usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1

/usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so

/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so

/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.la

/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.a

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.spec

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.so.1

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.so

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.la

/usr/local/lib64/libgomp.a

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.spec

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.so.1.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.so.1

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.so

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.la

/usr/local/lib64/libitm.a

/usr/local/lib64/libatomic.so.1.2.0

/usr/local/lib64/libatomic.so.1

/usr/local/lib64/libatomic.so

/usr/local/lib64/libatomic.la

/usr/local/lib64/libatomic.a

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.audio.sys.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.codec.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.kws.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.lu.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.extension.mas.so

/usr/local/lib64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.java.bindings.so

/usr/local/lib64/libcc1.so.0.0.0

/usr/local/lib64/libcc1.so.0

/usr/local/lib64/libcc1.so

/usr/local/lib64/libcc1.la

/usr/local/lib64/libsupc++.la

/usr/local/lib64/libsupc++.a

/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++fs.la
```

I've transferred the files located in speechSDK.jar - /lib/centos7-x64 here as well. (I've tried including them separately in -Djava.library.path too)

LE3: This is the last iteration of the commands I used to try to get it to work:

```
sudo java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/export/home/fos/tmpDir -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/speech2text/speechSDK-1.20/ASSETS/linux-x64:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/speech2text/speechSDK-1.20/ASSETS/centos7-x64 -jar extract-text-from-media-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` at your Java entry point prints what? Make sure all required native libraries are on it

Comment: @g00se It seemed like the project refused to read the libs located in /usr/local/lib64. I mananged to add them with -Djava.library.path, but it still doesn't seem to use them. I've also tried setting another -Djava.io.tmpdir, didn't help.

Comment: *It seemed like the project refused to read the libs located in /usr/local/lib64* What's in there btw? Can you do `find /usr/local/lib64` and show us?

Comment: @g00se Added edit to OP with folder contents.

Comment: Can I see the exact command used to launch with the `-D` options?

Comment: @g00se included in op edit

Comment: Ah OK. That seems OK. I think you could get an error like that with a missing file or a partially failed compilation